# Variable not defined during data analysis

Tags: python, pandas, undefined

I'm new to programming and I've looked at previous answers to this question but none seem relevant to this specific query.

I'm learning to analyse data with python.

This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

import os

os.chdir('/Users/Benjy/Documents/Python/Data Analysis Python')

unames = ['user_id', 'gender', 'age', 'occupation', 'zip']
users = pd.read_table('ml-1m/users.dat', sep='::', header = None, names = unames)

rnames = ['user_id', 'movie_id', 'rating', 'timestamp'] 
ratings = pd.read_table('ml-1m/ratings.dat', sep='::', header = None, names = rnames)

mnames = ['movie_id', 'title', 'genres']
movies = pd.read_table('ml-1m/movies.dat', sep='::', header = None, names = mnames)

data = pd.merge(pd.merge(ratings, users), movies)


mean_ratings=data.pivot_table('ratings',rows='title', cols='gender',aggfunc='mean')
```

I keep getting an error saying mean_ratings is not defined...but surely it is defined in the last line of code above?

Comment: you are passing `ratings` as a string on the `pivot_table()` function where a table is expected. Remove the quotes and try again. Like so: `mean_ratings=data.pivot_table(ratings,rows='title', cols='gender',aggfunc='mean')`

Comment: Tried that - still the same error!

Comment: Can you provide the full error message you are receiving?

Comment: It would also be nice to get the files you are using. In which line does the error occur?

Comment: and based on the documentation it does not look like `pivot_table` takes argument `rows`. Who wrote that code Benjy?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis In earlier versions of pandas, the parameter index was named rows.

Comment: try this I think this will work `mean_ratings=data.pivot_table('rating',index='title',columns='gender',aggfunc='mean')`.

Comment: perfect - thanks so much, I was referring to an obviously out of date book!

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work: `mean_ratings=data.pivot_table('rating',index='title',columns='gender',aggfunc='‌​mean')`